# Greatest product of five consecutive digits in a 1000-digit number

Tags: language-agnostic

I am working through the problems on project Euler and am not too certain if my understanding of the question is correct.

Problem 8 is as follows:

> Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number.

I have taken this to mean the following:

I need to find any five numbers that run consecutively in the 1000 digit number and then add these up to get the total. I am assuming that the size of the numbers could be anything, i.e. 1,2,3 or 12,13,14 or 123,124,124 or 1234,1235,1236 etc.

Is my understanding of this correct, or have I misunderstood the question?

**Note:** Please don't supply code or the solution, that I need to solve myself.

Comment: product is multiplication, not addition

Comment: Aargh I was looking for all pairs of consecutive digits (eg 2,3) which are 9 distinct of it. Then creating subsets containing 5 of these pairs and then figure out which one is biggest if all digits are multiplied with each other.. anyway I learned something..

Comment: I misunderstood this question in another way, reading _digit_ as _number_ -- i.e. I was trying to find the largest number `n` such that `str(n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*(n-4)) in str(bignum)` -- which means that `n` can have up to 200 digits. This problem is _slightly_ harder to solve, to put it mildly.

Comment: I had trouble understanding this question too.  I also originally came to the same conclusion about consecutive numbers.

Comment: Also a hint, solving this problem might help you later implement or learn rolling checksum :D

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The number is:

> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

- The first five consecutive digits are: 73167. Their product is 7*3*1*6*7=882
- The next five consecutive digits are: 31671. Their product is 3*1*6*7*1=126
- The next five consecutive digits are: 16717. Their product is 1*6*7*1*7=294

And so on. Note the overlap. Now, find the five consecutive digits whose product is maximal over the whole 1000-digit number.

Comment: A non-programmer friend of mine figured this out by looking at it in less than two minutes.  o.O

Comment: @P.Brian: I think I see a 3d image there.

Comment: Ok this was extremely confusing and misleading for me. I looked up the definition of consecutive and it is defined as a repeating pattern! Explained well in this [forum post](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/58752.html) I was looking for numbers like 1-2-3, 4-5-6, 7-8-9. Not a 5 digit subset of the number (7-3-1-6-7, 3-1-6-7-1). Wow talk about a waste of time coding it the wrong way!

Comment: google defines it as "following continuously".  That is consistent with how the problem uses it.

Answer (score 6):

A digit is a single 0-9 in the string representing the number.  So the number 12345 has 5 digits.  1234554321 has 10 digits.

The product is the multiplicative total, not the added total.  So the product of 3, 5 and 7 is 105.

A (somewhat clunky) way of rephrasing the question would be:

Given a 1000-digit number, select 5 consecutive digits from it that, when taken as individual numbers and multiplied together, give the largest result.

Answer (score 2):

Five single digits. 1, 5, 8... whatever shows up in the big number, all in a row. So if a chunk read "...47946285..." Then you could use "47946", "79462", "94628", "46285", etc.

Answer (score -1):

Only improvisation in my solution is, avoiding unnecessary computations by looking ahead.

```
package com.euler;

public class Euler8 {
    public static void main(String[] ar) throws Exception {
        String s = 
                "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" + 
                "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" + 
                "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" + 
                "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" + 
                "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" + 
                "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" + 
                "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" + 
                "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" + 
                "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" + 
                "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" + 
                "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" + 
                "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" + 
                "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" + 
                "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" + 
                "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" + 
                "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" + 
                "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" + 
                "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" + 
                "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" + 
                "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450" ;
        Integer[] tokens = new Integer[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            tokens[i] = (int) s.charAt(i)-48;
        }

        int prod = 1;
        int[] numberSet = new int[5];
        int prodCounter = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<tokens.length-4; i++) {
            // Look ahead: if they are zeros in next 5 numbers, just jump.
            if ( tokens[i] == 0) {
                i = i+1;
                continue;
            } else if ( tokens[i+1] == 0) {
                i = i+2;                
                continue;
            } else if ( tokens[i+2] == 0) {
                i = i+3;
                continue;
            } else if ( tokens[i+3] == 0) {
                i = i+4;                
                continue;                           
            } else if ( tokens[i+4] == 0) {
                i = i+5;                
                continue;               
            }           
            int localProd = tokens[i] * tokens[i+1] * tokens[i+2] * tokens[i+3] * tokens[i+4];
            System.out.println("" + (prodCounter++) + ")" + tokens[i] + "*" + tokens[i+1] + "*" + tokens[i+2] + "*" + tokens[i+3] + "*" + tokens[i+4] + " = " + localProd);
            if (localProd > prod) {
                prod = localProd;
                numberSet[0] = tokens[i];
                numberSet[1] = tokens[i+1];
                numberSet[2] = tokens[i+2];
                numberSet[3] = tokens[i+3];
                numberSet[4] = tokens[i+4];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Largest Prod = " + prod  + " By: (" + numberSet[0] + " , " + numberSet[1] + " ,  " + numberSet[2] + " , " + numberSet[3] + " , " + numberSet[4] + ")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will get:
Numbers: 99879
Product: 40824

```
$no = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
$x = 0;
$a = 0;
$max = 0;
while($a != 63450){
    $a = substr($no, $x, 5);
    $prod = substr($a, 0, 1) * substr($a, 1, 1) * substr($a, 2, 1)* substr($a, 3, 1) * substr($a, 4, 1);
    if($prod >= $max){
        $max = $prod;
        $theno = $a;
    }
    $x++;
}
echo 'Numbers: '.$theno.'<br>';
echo 'Product: '.$max;
```

Comment: from the question: PS. Please dont supply code or the solution, that I need to solve myself.

Answer (score -1):

This is my personal solution, using a bit of the brutal force:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim v() As Integer = {7, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 9, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 9, 6, 7, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9, 1, 9, 4, 9, 3, 4, 9, 6, 9, 8, 3, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 7, 7, 4, 5, 0, 6, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 9, 5, 7, 8, 3, 1, 8, 0, 1, 6, 9, 8, 4, 8, 0, 1, 8, 6, 9, 4, 7, 8, 8, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3, 8, 5, 8, 6, 1, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 1, 1, 2, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 5, 4, 5, 9, 5, 0, 1, 7, 3, 7, 9, 5, 8, 3, 3, 1, 9, 5, 2, 8, 5, 3, 2, 0, 8, 8, 0, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 7, 1, 5, 8, 5, 2, 3, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 1, 5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 9, 0, 9, 6, 3, 2, 9, 5, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 4, 8, 9, 5, 0, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6, 1, 7, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 4, 0, 3, 0, 9, 8, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 2, 2, 3, 8, 3, 1, 1, 3, 6, 2, 2, 2, 9, 8, 9, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 8, 0, 3, 0, 8, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 7, 6, 6, 1, 4, 2, 8, 2, 8, 0, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 6, 4, 5, 2, 3, 8, 7, 4, 9, 3, 0, 3, 5, 8, 9, 0, 7, 2, 9, 6, 2, 9, 0, 4, 9, 1, 5, 6, 0, 4, 4, 0, 7, 7, 2, 3, 9, 0, 7, 1, 3, 8, 1, 0, 5, 1, 5, 8, 5, 9, 3, 0, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 0, 1, 7, 2, 4, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 8, 8, 3, 9, 9, 8, 7, 9, 7, 9, 0, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 4, 9, 2, 1, 9, 0, 1, 6, 9, 9, 7, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 9, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 3, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 8, 0, 9, 7, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 0, 5, 9, 4, 7, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 8, 4, 9, 0, 7, 7, 1, 1, 6, 7, 0, 5, 5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 6, 0, 4, 8, 3, 9, 5, 8, 6, 4, 4, 6, 7, 0, 6, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 3, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7, 4, 0, 6, 4, 9, 5, 5, 1, 4, 9, 2, 9, 0, 8, 6, 2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 8, 4, 6, 8, 6, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 8, 3, 9, 7, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 7, 5, 6, 5, 7, 0, 5, 6, 0, 5, 7, 4, 9, 0, 2, 6, 1, 4, 0, 7, 9, 7, 2, 9, 6, 8, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5, 1, 0, 0, 4, 7, 4, 8, 2, 1, 6, 6, 3, 7, 0, 4, 8, 4, 4, 0, 3, 1, 9, 9, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 9, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 5, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 7, 5, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 1, 1, 6, 4, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 4, 7, 9, 9, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 0, 8, 6, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 1, 3, 9, 1, 9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 2, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 6, 1, 7, 8, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3, 5, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 2, 9, 4, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2, 8, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 4, 2, 6, 0, 7, 6, 9, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 2, 6, 7, 1, 0, 5, 5, 6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 3, 7, 0, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 0, 6, 9, 4, 1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 6, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 7, 1, 9, 8, 4, 0, 3, 8, 5, 0, 9, 6, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 2, 9, 8, 1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 8, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9, 2, 7, 2, 4, 4, 2, 8, 4, 9, 0, 9, 1, 8, 8, 8, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 6, 0, 9, 7, 9, 1, 9, 1, 3, 3, 8, 7, 5, 4, 9, 9, 2, 0, 0, 5, 2, 4, 0, 6, 3, 6, 8, 9, 9, 1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6, 0, 6, 0, 5, 8, 8, 6, 1, 1, 6, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 4, 0, 5, 0, 7, 7, 5, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 9, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 7, 2, 5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 6, 2, 6, 9, 5, 6, 1, 8, 8, 2, 6, 7, 0, 4, 2, 8, 2, 5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 0, 0, 8, 2, 3, 2, 5, 7, 5, 3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 7, 5, 2, 9, 6, 3, 4, 5, 0}
        Dim n = v.Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine(ElementoMax(v))
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Function ElementMax(vett() As Integer)

    Dim MAX, temp1, temp2, temp

    MAX = vett(0) * vett(1) * vett(2) * vett(3) * vett(4) * vett(5) * vett(6) * vett(7) * vett(8) * vett(9) * vett(10) * vett(11) * vett(12)
        For i = 1 To (vett.Length - 13)

            temp1 = vett(i) * vett(i + 1) * vett(i + 2) * vett(i + 3) * vett(i + 4) *       vett(i + 5) * vett(i + 6) * vett(i + 7) * vett(i + 8) * vett(i + 9) * vett(i + 10)* vett(i + 11) * vett(i + 12)
            temp2 = vett(i + 5) * vett(i + 6) * vett(i + 7) * vett(i + 8) * vett(i + 9) * vett(i + 10) * vett(i + 11) * vett(i + 12)
            temp = temp1 * temp2

            If temp > MAX Then
                MAX = temp
            End If
        Next
        Return MAX
    End Function

End Module
```

and the result is... ;-)

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Problem008
{
    public static int checkInt(String s)
    {
        int product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Character c = new Character(s.charAt(i));
            String tmp = c.toString();
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
            product *= temp;
        }
        return product;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String BigNum = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        String snip;
        int largest = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= (BigNum.length()-5); i++)
        {
            snip = null;

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                char c = BigNum.charAt(i+j);
                snip += c;
            }
            if (checkInt(snip) > largest)
                largest = checkInt(snip);
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(largest);
            System.out.println(end-begin + "ms");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `PS. Please dont supply code or the solution, that I need to solve myself.` The asker didn't want the code itself, s(he) wanted an explanation.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class ProjectEuler8
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int list[] = new int[1000];
        int max = 0;
        String str = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++)
            list[index] = str.charAt(index) - 48;
        for (int count = 0; count < 996; count++)
        {
            int product = list[count] * list[count + 1] * list[count + 2] * list[count + 3] * list[count + 4];
            if (product > max) max = product;
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Simple is better, isn't it?

Comment: PS. Please don't supply code or the solution, that I need to solve myself.

Answer (score -3):

**In C** I copied it in a txt file and read from it, or you can just initialise string at the beginning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *a;
    a=fopen("Long.txt","r");
    char s[1001];
    fscanf(a,"%s",s);
char p[6];

int i=0,x,prdmax=1,m,n;
while(s[i]!='\0')
{
    p[0]=s[i];
    p[1]=s[i+1];
    p[2]=s[i+2];
    p[3]=s[i+3];
    p[4]=s[i+4];
    p[5]='\0';

    x=atoi(p);
    n=x;
    int prd=1;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        int q=x%10;
        prd*=q;
        x/=10;
    }

    if(prd>prdmax)
    {
        prdmax=prd;
        m=n;
    }
    i++;
}

printf("Numbers are: %d\n Largest product is: %d",m,prdmax);

fclose(a);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but OP asked not to give the code to solution of the problem. He just wanted to understand the problem. You should respect that.