# Array of a very long list of ints

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to solve the 8th problem of the project Euler and I'm stuck because I can't manage to create a very long array of char.

There must be a stupid semantic issue, but I'm unable to find it.

```
   char cifre[] = "very long list of numbers here";
```

Comment: How long is "very long"?

Comment: What does the compiler say? What is the real problem?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167339/project-euler-problem-8-help-with-understanding-requirement

Comment: Compilers are expected to support string literals up to 4095 characters long (5.4.2.1/1), with 4096 the minimum acceptable implementation-defined limit. Euler problem 8 only calls for 1000, so nothing obviously wrong here. If you could stir yourself to report the compiler or runtime error that you're seeing, that might help ;-p

Comment: Xcode has given me two errors, it says: missing terminating "" character

Comment: @Francesco: Why are you so against sharing the errors that you are seeing. Why don't you get that they are helpful?

Comment: @Francesco: Then you're probably missing the close quote. Did you split the string into lines, like it is on the Project Euler page? You'll probably have to quote each line and let the implicit concatenation join them for you.

Comment: All you had to do to get the answer to your problem was to post your code! Next time please please please post your code so that we can help you more easily without having to guess. And include the error messages!

Comment: PE#8 contains 1000 characters, shouldn't be a problem!

Comment: PS: I've just solved PE#8 :-) It is really good simple task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such example works with gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *x = 
"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
;

    printf ("%s",x);
}
```

It prints your long number on screen without any problem. Symbol \ in string tells compiler that string literal is continued on next line. You are free to modify this example as you want. But please note that modifying content of string pointed by x isn't good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Does adding a `\` after each line of that 1000 digit number help?

It allows you to enter longer literals that span multiple lines.
Alternatively, surround each line of that long string in `"`, it will do the same thing.

Comment: I think this can be the solution, I'm trying

Comment: something like this?
    char cifre[] = {"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
 \96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
 \85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
 \12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
 \66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
 \62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
 \30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
 \70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
 \65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
 \52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"};

Comment: @Francesco: no, at the end of the line, not at the beginning of the new one.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you should probably allocate it dynamically. However, your question is somewhat vague as you didn't indicate where you are running into trouble or what your idea of "very long" is.

But here's some code to get you started:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10240

char* pArray = (char*)malloc(ARRAY_SIZE);
memset(pArray, 0, ARRAY_SIZE);
free(pArray);
```

Comment: PE#8 contains 1000 character: Problem description: "Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number."