# Project Euler 8

Tags: java, math

I've read some topics on the project Euler problem 8. However I don't know why my code is giving me the wrong answer.

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Euler8 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bigNumber = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
            + "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
            + "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
            + "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
            + "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
            + "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
            + "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
            + "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
            + "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
            + "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
            + "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
            + "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
            + "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
            + "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
            + "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
            + "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
            + "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
            + "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
            + "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
            + "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
            ;
    ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int counter = 1;
    int current = 0;
    int product = 1;
    int maximumProduct = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < bigNumber.length(); i++)  {
        String b = "" + bigNumber.charAt(i);
        current = Integer.parseInt(b);
        myArray.add(current);
        if(counter % 5 == 0) {

            for(int x : myArray) {
                product = x * product;
            }
            if(product > maximumProduct) {
                maximumProduct = product;
            }
            myArray.clear();
            product = 1;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(maximumProduct);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the answer 31752 and the right one is 40824. Since this is for a homework I can't copy the solution to the problem so I would like any explanation on why my code is not working so I can fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Would your code recognize the maximum product of five consecutive digits in the string `"09999900000000000000000000"`? If not, why?

Comment: As a side note, you can convert a digit `char` to an `int` more concise: `int foo = bigNumber.charAt(i) - '0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not considering the right elements to multiply. Each product is obtained by multiplying 5 consecutive digits, for each digit the code below saves these digits in `myArray`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
   String bigNumber = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                + "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                + "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                + "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                + "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                + "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                + "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                + "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                + "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                + "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                + "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                + "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                + "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                + "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                + "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                + "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                + "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                + "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                + "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                + "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
                ;

                ;
        ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int counter = 1;
        int current = 0;
        int product = 1;
        int maximumProduct = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < bigNumber.length(); i++)  {
            String b = "" + bigNumber.charAt(i);
            current = Integer.parseInt(b);
            myArray.add(current);
            counter++;
            if(counter == 5) {
                for(int x : myArray) {
                    product = x * product;
                }
                if(product > maximumProduct) {
                    maximumProduct = product;

                }
               myArray.remove(0);
               product = 1;
            }
            counter=myArray.size();
        }
        System.out.println(maximumProduct);
        }
}
```

See also [Greatest product of five consecutive digits in a 1000-digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167339/project-euler-problem-8-help-with-understanding-requirement)

Comment: Oooh!! I got it now! Thank you very much! now I understand it better! :)