# Finding the max product of consecutive digits (Project Euler #8)

Tags: java, list, math

[Project Euler problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) involves finding the largest product of 13 consecutive digits in a 1000-digit number. I've tried to solve this problem with the code below, but the results I am getting are too small by a factor of about 10. What have I done wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class eight {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String number="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    String input = "782";
    int value = 782;
    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (char ch : number.toCharArray()){
        int element_add=Character.getNumericValue(ch);
       x.add(element_add);
    }
    int check_count=0;
    int multiply_value=0;
    int multiply_value_max=0;
    while(check_count<986){
    multiply_value=(x.get(check_count))*(x.get(check_count+1))*(x.get(check_count+2))*(x.get(check_count+3))*(x.get(check_count+4))*(x.get(check_count+5))*(x.get(check_count+6))*(x.get(check_count+7))*(x.get(check_count+8))*(x.get(check_count+9))*(x.get(check_count+10))*(x.get(check_count+11))*(x.get(check_count+12));
    if(multiply_value>multiply_value_max){
        multiply_value_max=multiply_value;
    }
    check_count++;
    }
    System.out.println(multiply_value_max);



    }

}
```

Comment: What is the task/goal?

Comment: Please include the problem statement in your question, with a link to the original Project Euler question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project Euler 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038591/project-euler-8)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the upper bound for the answer can be greater than maximum value of int. Therefore, you need to use the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class, or at the very least `long`, to store the result. To ensure that the operations are carried out with sufficient precision, you want to store the individual digits in the same precision or convert them to the precision as you multiply them.

You can also save yourself some typing and boilerplate errors by handling the consecutive multiplication with a for loop.

Comment: 32-bit arithmetic is the problem, not `getNumericValue` (which should work fine with the characters `0` to `9`). You could save a lot more time by keeping a running product. At each step, divide by `digit[i-1]` and multiply by `digit[i+12]`.

Comment: Using long still gave the wrong answer, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @samrobbins I suggest you debug your code. Try running with some smaller examples. Does your code output 2541865828329 when the input string is `"9999999999999"`?